# Android Studio 4.1 xml problem (plz help)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, syntax-error

I'm trying to use buttons and images in my MainActivity.kt, but somehow when I give them an id in activity_main.xml as you see in the code below:

```js
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

when I try using them in MainActivity.kt it doesn't recognize them at all! auto import for editor is on, but for example, if I type **"firstbtn"** in MainActivity.kt there would be no auto complete and the Error : "Unresolved reference: firstbtn" would appear.
Please Help if you know how can I solve it, I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onCreate function of MainActivity.kt type

```
val firstbtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.firstbtn)
```

Or if you don't need the reference later, use a scope function, for example *apply* like so:

```
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.firstbtn).apply{
        //configure firstbtn for your needs
    }
```

Another solution is to use an extension plugin. Add it to your module build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    [...]
}
```

In your activity import the package

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Then you can use the views like you originally wanted to (just type the id of the view, e.g. *firstbtn*).

Comment: Thanks, A lot!!! so every time I should Declare it locally like this?

Comment: I mean, is there a general solution for it?

Comment: @Mehrshad I edited the answer, with probably what you mean by general solution.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant! Thanks alot <3